# Hadoop for Mobile Devices

Tags: mobile, hadoop

I am working on a project where I need to run Hadoop Over  Mobile devices. I have searched  "Mobile Hadoop" but I was not able to find any distribution of Hadoop which runs over mobile devices. Is there any distribution of Hadoop which runs  over Mobile and if not, How can I write my own Hadoop which can do it.

Answer (score 1):

To run Hadoop on Mobile devices seems a joke. Typically, Hadoop runs on commodity hardware. What do you exactly mean by **Mobile devices**?  If you mean mobile phone, may there not exist Hadoop distributions for your project. Even though you can deploy Hadoop on a Mobile devices cluster, what can that cluster do?

Comment: As Today's Smart Phone have also lot of computing power ,So Mobile Phone can also be used as a Node for Hadoop device e.g. Something Similar proposed here. http://reports-archive.adm.cs.cmu.edu/anon/2009/CMU-CS-09-164.pdf . I wanted to know if there are any implementation of this kind of Idea.

Comment: Even though some research project propose this idea, its usefulness is limited. How many users are willing to contribute their devices for this? Volunteer computing is a hot topic several years ago. If you have more materails, I also want to learn that. Thanks for this question.